# How can I achieve this style in iOS?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, ios5, xcode4.3

In my app, I'd like to show a popup screen within my UITableViewController screen listing a few options for the user to select from.

Similar to how the Facebook app works (unfortunately I have no requests) :(

[image: Facebook friends requests table]

So I have two questions:

1) The black, shaded frame we see here seems to be a common style that I see a lot, especially in iPad apps. Is this just coincidence that apps use the same style? Is it a 3rd party plugin that others are using? Or is it a new, native part of the iOS SDK?

2) If I am to build this subview myself, what kind of structure would be best? I'd thought of:

```
UIImageView (for the background) > 
    UILabel (containing the header)
    UITableView (containing my sub-table)
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's `UIPopoverController`, native component for iPad, but not for iPhone.
For iPhone use 3rd party frameworks, like this one:
http://www.50pixels.com/blog/labs/open-library-fppopover-ipad-like-popovers-for-iphone/